# NetBeans doesn't see style.css

Tags: css, servlets

I have a Servlet/JSP webapp. So now I am having troubles in pointing NetBeans to my style.css file. If stylesheet is being placed in WEB-INF or META-INF or outside them in Web Pages dir - everything works fine. But I need to store this file in a css folder under  src/main/resources/css/style.css 
The problem is that I can't refer to style.css is it is outside Web Pages dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot place a css file outside the pages folder simply because everything exept that folder is not accessible by the Client. Dont forget that a css file is included like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/notification.css" />
```

You dont want someone to change it to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/MyPreciousJavaFile.java" />` and simply get the coding of any other file.

Comment: Now THAT makes sense. Thanks a lot :)
I was fighting this problem for a few hours because my mentor told me that it's my "smart NetBeans" problem and he wanted the webapp to be structured exactly this way: css file under resources. 
Hope, he will change his mind after I have sent him your answer.

Thank you a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

src/main/resources- is the directory of properties file or xml file that used by Java classes.
For css you should place your file in webapp directory like src/main/webapp/resources. Client can't get any access outside of webapp directory.