# NetBeans jqGrid CSS issue

Tags: css, netbeans, jqgrid

I am using netbeans ide for programming in that recently I am adding jqgrid application for that I am adding following link and script in head of the html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="design/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="design/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="design/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="design/grid.locale-en.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="design/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" ></script>
```

the above links ui.jqgrid.css shows error in netbeans the error is unexpected token dot found the lines are below

```
* html .jqgrid-overlay {width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth+'px');height: expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+'px');}
* .jqgrid-overlay iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1;width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth+'px');height: expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+'px');}
* iframe.jqm {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1;width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth+'px');height: expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+'px');}
```

please give me your guidance to resolve this issue

Comment: could it be foulder problem like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17230323/1849444)?

Comment: No it is not a folder issue it is showing error in css file only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you use some **old version of jqGrid**? Look at [the ui.jqgrid.css file](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css) of jqGrid 4.7.0 or ui.jqgrid.css of jqGrid 4.6.0 and search for `expression`. You will find the text **only in comments**. If you use some old version of jqGrid (like 4.5.4 or earlier) you should update it to 4.6.0/4.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of NetBeans, you may easily fix this issue being reported by filtering out this kind of parsing errors.

To do so, you can **click on the red indicator and choose one of the options** so that either errors like these or the current file can be ignored!